# JavaScript && Operator Without =

Tags: javascript, operators

I came across this line:

```js
while (char = word[i++]) {
  if (!current[char]) { break; }
  current = current[char];
  prefix += char;
  current.word && found.push(prefix); //??
}
```

What does the AND (current.word && found.push(prefix)) operator mean in this situation?

Is this the equivalent to both those expressions being true? I tried separating the expressions and set to true but I do not think that is the equivalent...

Comment: `x() && y()`, where the result of the expression is not used, is equivalent to `if (x()) { y() }`. I am not a fan of this code-style preference and consider it "overly clever, without adding meaningful value".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` checks if both expression on either side are truthy, i.e. that `this AND this` are both truthy.

The specs says

> *Logical AND (&&) `expr1 && expr2`*
>   Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`.
>   Thus, when used with
>   Boolean values, `&&` returns true if both operands can be converted to
>   true; otherwise, returns false.

It always checks from left to right, starting with the left side expression

Knowing this, if the expression on the left side of `&&` is falsy, there's no reason to check the right side, as the result will be falsy if the first expression is falsy.

In other words, if `current.word` is falsy, it ends there.
If `current.word` is truthy, it has to check the right side of `&&` as well, and executes the `found.push(prefix)` to see if that expression is falsy or truthy.

More simply, it could be written

```
if ( current.word ) found.push(prefix);
```

but someone was being clever

Comment: you should note that js linters (like jslint/jshint etc) will complain about the code - despite the fact that js linters "all suck"

Comment: Also add that in this case, the `&&` operator is called a "guard operator", if you need the right words to google in the future.

Comment: i would call it as smart and small version of if condition where it will check all the conditions from left, one by one for truth and will execute the right last one.